# Software PWM on AVR using delay

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, pulse, atmega16, mikroc

I am trying to accomplish a simple PWM generation using delays on an AVR ATMega16

What i am trying to do is simply fade a led from 100% to 0% duty cycle, and later i will expand it to control two colors of a bicolor led to have a nice effect.

I have done this in mikroC with PICs before, but somehow it's not as easy in avr-gcc, or maybe i am missing something.

My problem here is that i want the led to fade completely in 3 seconds, but i feel its fading faster. I also think that it's spending more time on high duty cycles than on low ones. I mean that i see the led bright for a bit, then it fades, but when it becomes dim it moves to different duty cycles very fast or so i think..

Any ideas you might have on what i am missing ?

Code is available here : http://ideone.com/lUP5f

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a problem with the fuse settings. The clock is usually controlled by fuses not by the define. However the delay function uses the #define F_CPU. Can you post your fuse settings?

Is there a specific reason that you want to use delay instead of a timer to generate the PWM? In case you want to have a look at timers I can recommend these Tutorials to you:1)[Timer Tutorial](http://deans-avr-tutorials.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Timers/Output/Timers.pdf) 2)[PWM](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=68302)

Edit: btw

```
 uint8_t b = 1000;
```

uint8_t allows values from 0 to 255 the compiler usually generates a warning for this:

> ../test.c:16: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type

Comment: thanks, im sure its not a fuse setting because they were set for me by a friend who has already done this :)
but other than that, your links are very helpful and so is the warning about the max value, its kinda weird that my avr-gcc didn't pop that one out... any option i should specify so it shows warnings too ?

Comment: Thanks again, i recoded the whole thing from scratch and it works like a charm right now ! It was mainly because of the uint8_t so i owe you one ;) but any ideas if there is a flag in the command line that i should pass to avr-gcc to get all warnings too ?

Comment: This warning should pop up. Try using -Werror to show all warnings as errors

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that LEDs are not linear.
So it doesn't work to turn them on for example with 50% to reduce their brightness to 50%..

You can use a predefinied table (for example here: http://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/LED-Fading#Das_Demoprogramm)

You don't need to be able to read german. Just study this piece of code..
There are some tables for example for 16 bit PWM (pwmtable_16[]).

So you can write:

`delay_us(pwmtable_16[a]);`

instead of

`delay_us(a);`

Comment: Thanks! That's very enlightening, i thought it was just me but it turns out its the LEDs so its nice to know :)